How to filter PropertyColumn with DateTime property but display string property?
I have a MudDataGrid bound to a collection of Shipment objects. The shipment object has two properties for the Shipment date. Shipment.PickupDate is a DateTime property. Shipment.PickupScheduledEndDateTime is a string.
My assignment is to add a PropertyColumn that uses Shipment.PickupDate for filtering and sorting, but displays Shipment.PickupScheduledEndDateTime. Is that possible?
This works great for filtering:
<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.PickupDate" Title="Shipping Date" IsEditable="false"/>

but I'm supposed to display PickupScheduledEndDateTime instead of PickupDate.

You need to use a TemplateColumn.  You need to provide a [MRE] if you want a more detailed answer.

You can use a PropertyColumn but you need to work with the CellTemplate.
<MudDataGrid SortMode="SortMode.Single">
<Columns>
<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.CreatedAt" Title="CreatedAt" InitialDirection="SortDirection.Descending">
     <CellTemplate>
         @context.Item.CreatedAt.ToLocalTime().ToString("g")
     </CellTemplate>
   </PropertyColumn>
 </Columns>
...

This works well in our project.
